# @@ROWCOUNT is returning always zero in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rowcount

Here is my stored procedure

```
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[TestStoProc]    Script Date: 21.09.2023 13:32:40 ******/ 
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PurgeSyncOperations] 
       -- Parameters for the stored procedure here
         @Date datetime, 
         @CustomerNumber nvarchar(10),
         @count int = 0 output
    AS
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @row INT;
            SET @row = 1;

            WHILE @row > 0
                BEGIN
                -- Statements for archiving and deletion

                    //some query to insert data

                    //some query to delete data

                    SET @row = @@ROWCOUNT;
                    SET @count = @count + @@ROWCOUNT
                END
        END
```

I am getting always zero from this stored procedure.
Need help on this.

Comment: The bigger question is why do you think you need a loop here? I would focus my effort on getting rid of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

```sql
SET @row = @@ROWCOUNT;
SET @count = @count + @@ROWCOUNT
```

assigns rowcount from the set @row = @@rowcount operation.

Surely you want:

```sql
SET @row = @@ROWCOUNT;
SET @count = @count + @row
```

Comment: This is working.
Thanks...

Comment: Just to point it out - you can simplify this down to SET @count += @@ROWCOUNT;  instead of pulling the row count and then adding that to count.

Comment: yeah, but you need to set @row to be able to jump out too